# System of (non linear) equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

Let $n \geq 2$.

Could it be proved that the following system, with $z_k\in \mathbb C$,

$
\begin{cases}
  z_1^n + z_{n}z_1^{n-1} + z_{n-1}z_1^{n-2} + \cdots + z_2z_1+z_1 & = 0 \\
   z_2^n + z_{n}z_2^{n-1} + z_{n-1}z_2^{n-2} + \cdots + z_2z_2+z_1 &= 0
  \\
  z_3^n + \color{blue}{z_{n}z_3^{n-1}} + z_{n-1}z_3^{n-2} + \cdots + z_2z_3+z_1
                                                                   &=0 \\
\vdots &=\vdots\\
  z_n^n + \color{blue}{z_{n}^{n}} + z_{n-1}z_n^{n-2} + \cdots +z_2z_n+z_1
                                                                   &=0 
\end{cases}$

has a finite set of solutions?

Remark: For $n=2$ it is easy, for $n=3$ a bit more work by doable.

Comment: For $n=3$, assuming the system,$$\begin{align}
z_1^3 + z_3 z_1^2 + z_2 z_1 + z_1 =0\\ 
z_2^3 + z_3 z_2^2 + z_2 z_2 + z_1 =0\\ 
z_3^3 + z_3 z_3^2 + z_2 z_3 + z_1 =0
\end{align}$$ an interesting (but not unique solution) is,$$z_1 = z_2,\;\;z_3 = \frac{-(z_2^2+z_2+1)}{z_2},\;\;z_2 = -1/T-1$$ where $T$ is the *tribonacci constant*, or the root of $T^3-T^2-T-1=0.$

Comment: How did this system arise? You might get more answers if you give the background behind it.  :)